# Literal String Type Inference for Abstract Class Member values

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, member

The following typescript code leads to an error (typescript v3.8.3). Why?

```js
class A {
    public foobar: 'foo' | 'bar' = 'bar';
}

class B extends A {
    public foobar = 'foo';  // --> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"foo" | "bar"'
}
```

Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQA4FcBGICWw0AZgPYnZgBOAXNAOSkl3QA+9FlzAvO1XQNxIAvkiShIMAELQApgA8ALjIB2AExjxkaDDnyFGHaDwZkBwpEA

I offer an answer to this question below, but I will be happy to hear about alternatives to achieve the same purpose that would not require writing the constructor or duplicating the type definition in the child classes.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may find discriminated union types useful

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'foo' is inferred to be a string, which allows `B.foobar` to be inferred to be a string, which then conflicts with type of the parent class member `A.foobar`.

The following works, which doesn't do any type casting from my level of understanding:

```js
class A {
    public foobar: 'foo' | 'bar' = 'bar';
}

class B extends A {
    public foobar: 'foo' | 'bar' = 'foo';
}
```

The following also works, which forces typescript to infer the type of `B.foobar` from `A.foobar` instead of the string value.

```js
class A {
    public foobar: 'foo' | 'bar' = 'bar';
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.foobar = 'foo';
    }
}
```